# Arrayfire error with conditionals

Tags: c++, arrayfire

I am trying to saturate my arrays in ArrayFire.  I want all values greater than 0.75 to saturate to 1.0 and all less than 0.25 to saturate to 0.0.  I am using the following expressions.

```
a(a > 0.75) = 1.0;
a(a < 0.25) = 0.0;
```

Here is is an af::array type. It works for a while but as soon as I get an array where there are no values greater than 0.75 I get the following exception.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'af::exception'
  what():  ArrayFire Exception (Invalid input size:203):
In function verifyDims
In file src/api/c/data.cpp:36
Invalid dimension for argument 1
Expected: ndims >= 1

In function af::array af::constant(T, const af::dim4&, af::dtype) [with T = double; af::dtype = af_dtype]
In file src/api/cpp/data.cpp:28
```

If I call `af::print("", a > 0.75);` I get the following output right before it crashes.

```
[10 1 1 1]
         0 
         0 
         0 
         0 
         0 
         0 
         0 
         0 
         0 
         0
```

Is it somehow seeing that this array is all zeros (which it should be since non are greater than 0.75) and then saying the dimension is zero?  It it something I am doing wrong or is it a bug in their code?

The following code seems to fix it but I feel this solution is somewhat inefficient.

```
af::array bellow = a[levels - 1] < 0.25f;
af::array above = a[levels - 1] > 0.75f;

if(af::anyTrue<bool>(above))
    a[levels - 1](above) = 0.75f;

if(af::anyTrue<bool>(bellow))
    a[levels - 1](bellow) = 0.25f;
```

For those of you who want to see the entire function I am doing gradient decent in a neural network.  a is actually and array of type af::array.  I left that out to simplify the question.

```
void train(const float* in, const float* expected_out, float learning_rate)
{
    std::unique_ptr<af::array[]> a(new af::array[levels]),
            z(new af::array[levels]), d(new af::array[levels]);

    af::array in_array(inputs, in);
    af::array y(dims[levels - 1], expected_out);

    z[0] = af::matmul(weights[0], in_array) + biases[0];
    a[0] = sigma(z[0]);


    for(size_t i = 1; i < levels; i++)
    {
        z[i] = af::matmul(weights[i], a[i - 1]) + biases[i];
        a[i] = sigma(z[i]);
    }


    a[levels - 1](a[levels - 1] < 0.25f) = 0.0f;
    a[levels - 1](a[levels - 1] > 0.75f) = 1.0f;

    d[levels - 1] = (y - a[levels - 1]) * sigma_prime(z[levels - 1]);
    for(size_t i = levels - 1; i-- > 0;)
        d[i] = af::matmul(weights[i + 1].T(), d[i + 1]) * sigma_prime(z[i]);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < levels; i++)
    {
        biases[i] += learning_rate * d[i];
        weights[i] += learning_rate * af::matmul(d[i], (i ? a[i - 1] : in_array).T());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the piece of code which gives you the error.

Comment: I did it is the first piece of code.

Comment: `a(a > 0.75) = 1.0;
a(a < 0.25) = 0.0;`

Comment: A longer piece would be good. A function (with irrelevant parts snipped, but all parameter and local variable definitions visible), plus declarations of any global variables, is sort of minimum.

Comment: Nobody wants to see the entire function. Why is it that people only ever post either tiny isolated snippets that don't reproduce the problem, or their entire function/program? Sigh. [mcve]!

Comment: Um, the `a(a > 0.75) = 1.0; a(a < 0.25) = 0.0;` doesn't even appear in the code you added. Also, it'd be good to indicate with comments in code, which lines the exceptions or errors refer to.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that I pasted the code with something that fixed it.  I just changed it to the original code.  The fix I am using is described in the post and just seems like the inefficient and wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because of this [open bug about zero length arrays](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues/799) (**EDIT:** FIxed as of v3.4.0). This is a pervasive issue that we are trying to fix properly for some time now.

Here is the work around for your case. You don't even need indexing to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
a[levels - 1] = af::min(0.75, af::max(0.25, a[levels - 1]));
```

**EDIT:** As of 3.4, you can do the following to achieve the same functionality in arrayfire:

```
a[levels - 1] = af::clamp(a[levels - 1], 0.25, 0.75);
```

This method is much much faster than indexing for your case.

---

That said, there are some cases when you can not use `af::min` and `af::max` to replace indexing. In those cases, you could do something like this as a work around:

```
af::array cond = arr < some_val;
arr = arr * (1 - cond) + cond * other_val;
```

This should also be faster than indexing. However the arithmetic will not work if the arrays have `NAN` in them and you are trying to replace them. In which case you could fall back to one of the following functions.

Using select (uses additional memory):

```
arr = af::select(af::isNaN(arr), arr, other_val));
```

Using replace (replaces in place, no additional memory used):

```
af::replace(arr, af::isNaN(arr) other_val));
```

However some benchmarking showed us that `select` and `replace` can be slower than indexing in certain cases (which we are trying to fix). So you could try using the following work around for indexing if `select` / `replace` are slow in your algorithm.

```
af::array idx = af::where(af::isNaN(arr));
if (idx.elements()) arr(idx) = replace_val;
```

Note that indexing on a boolean `af::array` calls `af::where` internally. So this is as efficient as the following

```
arr(arr < some_val) = other_val;
```

with the added benefit of not failing for zero sized arrays.

**EDIT:** Added additional workarounds for posterity.